# Installing skmca python package

Tags: python, anaconda

I can't figure out how to install the python package named **skmca** ( MCA for sickit-learn ) : https://github.com/TomAugspurger/skmca

There is no **pip** or **conda** command available.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check their reference to the following page for PIP install:

https://github.com/MaxHalford/Prince

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a pip command:

```
$ pip install prince
```

Finishes with

> Successfully installed cycler-0.10.0 joblib-0.13.2 kiwisolver-1.1.0
>   matplotlib-3.1.0 numpy-1.16.3 pandas-0.24.2 prince-0.6.2
>   pyparsing-2.4.0 python-dateutil-2.8.0 pytz-2019.1 scikit-learn-0.21.2
>   scipy-1.3.0 six-1.12.0

Comment: yes. I was confused by the fact that the package name is **prince** and not **skmca**.